# Kafka cosumer poll not returning recording for low timeout

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer

Kafka consumer poll api not returning records to low timeout.
If I increase the timeout value in poll then records are coming.
I am not able to get understand this logic. Please help, following the code:

```
public ConsumerRecords<String, Map<String, String>> subscribeToQueue(String topic, QueueListener q) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "com.intuit.eventcollection.queue.KafkaJsonDeserializer");
    props.put("group.id", "test");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest"); 

    // Figure out where to start processing messages from
    KafkaConsumer<String, Map<String, String>> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, Map<String, String>>(
            props);
    kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));
    ConsumerRecords<String, Map<String, String>> records = null;
    // Start processing messages
    try {
        records = kafkaConsumer.poll(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Poll will return nothing if there are no new unconsumed messages published in the time period specified as the timeout to poll( timeout ).

Comment: I see the timeout definition as :- timeout - The time, in milliseconds, spent waiting in poll if data is not available. If 0, returns immediately with any records that are available now. Must not be negative. While testing I am continuously sending the data in topic and in same flow I am trying to consume the message with timeout as 100. But nothing is returned from topic. But when I increase the timeout to 200. Then messages starts coming out of the topic. As as your reply "no new unconsumed messages published in the time period " , this I cant understand while testing.